Python typehints: Union of type complex types not working as expected with user defined classes
I was trying to create a type alias that matches Callables with different numbers of arguments like this:
from typing import Callable

class C:
    # no __add__ method, so all statements below should give an error
    pass

type F[T1, T2] = Callable[[T1], T2] | Callable[[T1, T1], T2]

b: Callable[[C], C] = lambda a, b: a + b # error
a: Callable[[C, C], C] = lambda a, b: a + b # error


# but:
c: F[C, C] = lambda a, b: a + b # no error

But as illustrated it doesnt work if I instantiate it with a class C, as it should also give an error for c. It does work as expected with built-in types like that don't support +:
d: F[set, set] = lambda a, b: a + b # error

I am using the latest version of pyright (1.1.360)
Is this

a limitation of pyright?
or a bug of pyright?
or do need to do sth to make this work with classes?


This is a bug. The fix will be available in 1.1.361.

I've copied your code to an online playground for ease of access to the actual errors and inferred types.
Let's consider each statement in order:

The definition for a typechecks, other than the expected error than type C does not support the + operator (Operator "+" not supported for types "C" and "C").
This line would not produce an error when using int as int does implement the + operator. That might be why you are seeing a difference between "built-in types like int" and the class C.

The definition for b does not typecheck with Expression of type "(a: Unknown, b: Unknown) -> Unknown" is incompatible with declared type "() -> C".
This is expected, as the annotated specifies exactly 0 arguments (first generic argument in Callable[[], C]).

The definition for c typechecks without any errors.
This is unexpected as the + operator should produce the same error as in the definition of a. Unfortunately, Pyright infers the type Unknown for both arguments which behaves as Any, meaning + is presumed well-defined and the result of the operation is Unknown which is presumed compatible with C.
Beyond that, the function type does indeed match the annotation F[C, C] as the type of the lambda is inferred as Callable[[Unknown, Unknown], Unknown] which is compatible with the second option in the definition of F[C, C], namely Callable[[C, C], C].



I believe F does in fact represent the intended type i.e. "Callables with different numbers of arguments".
What might be confusing you here is that Pyright is producing errors for the use of the + operator which appear on the same lines as the type annotation. These errors, however, are not about the annotations themselves. These errors also go away when using type int as it supports the + operator.

Here are some experiments we can conduct to see that Pyright is actually doing the right thing:

Add a definition for __add__ (operator +) to C to fix the error in a:

def C:
    def __add__(self, other) -> "C":
        raise NotImplemented

a: Callable[[C, C], C] = lambda a, b: a + b # no error


Modify the body of b to match its type annotation:

b: Callable[[], C] = lambda: C() # no error


Explicitly specify the parameter types in the definition of c to expose the error about operator +:

def c_impl(a: C, b: C) -> C:
    return a + b # error: Operator "+" not supported for types "C" and "C"
c: F[C, C] = c_impl


Rewrite the definition of F to not allow 2-parameter functions to make c error and prove that it was checking the number of parameters:

type F[T1, T2] = Callable[[T1], T2]

c: F[C, C] = lambda a, b: a + b # error
# Expression of type "(a: C, b: Unknown) -> Unknown" is incompatible with declared type "F[C, C]"
#  Type "(a: C, b: Unknown) -> Unknown" is incompatible with type "F[C, C]"
#    Function accepts too few positional parameters; expected 2 but received 1 


The missing add method is not the issue. I didn't add one to demonstrate that, in the case of c, I don't get an error from pyright, even though the "+" is not supported. When I said it works with built-in types like int, I meant that for unsupported operators, c correctly gives an error.

I edited the question for clarification

Why does pyright infer the type Unknown for the lambda arguments in the case of c, but not for a and b? Is this a limitation/bug?

Ah, understood. I think this is a limitation in Pyright. I think that it reasonably propagates type information only towards the left-hand side of the assignment.
This means that in lhs = rhs, the type of lhs can be inferred from the type of rhs; but the type of rhs can never use any information from lhs.
This seems reasonable given how anemic and rare lambda function expressions are in Python.

It works for this:
g: Callable[[float], int] = lambda a: a

Yeah you're right - moreover it works with c: Callable[[C, C], C] = lambda a, b: a + b which should be equivalent to the original by referential transparency. Indeed seems like a bug!

Wait, my mistake. This seems to be caused by the union type actually. c: Callable[[C], C] | Callable[[C, C], C] also does not cause an error. My guess is the union is preventing type inference because you'd have to do it bidirectionally: 1) infer that the lambda has 2 arguments 2) infer that the arguments must be type C. This way neither direction can proceed on its own - you have to alternate rhs->lhs and lhs->rhs inference.

As maximsmol pointed out, the issue is that type inference is only done from the right-hand side to the left-hand side of an assignment, not the other way. For example this:
from typing import Callable

def foo1(a):
    return a

foo2: Callable[[float], int] = foo1

also doesn't give an error, even tho if you give a float to foo2 it doesn't return an int. (pyright playground)
edit: That doesn't seem to be the issue afterall, as this correctly gives an error:
g: Callable[[float], int] = lambda a: a

edit: It's a confirmed bug.

That's because the type of foo1 is inferred as (Unknown) -> Unknown. Try turning on strict mode.
